# Is it possible to change / edit the height of a component?

Tags: sketchup

I created a table with 3 feet long legs but I wanted to adjust the height to 2 feet.

The legs are modeled as 1 inch by 1 inch aluminum prisms as seen below.

I tried right clicking on the the component and selected edit but did not see a way to adjust the height.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your vote of confidence - I will add that we *typically* advise folks to wait (24 hours or so) before accepting an answer: that way you encourage more folks to look at your *currently still active* question and get a wider range of potentially good responses to choose from - once you accept an answer it doesn't show up as an active question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You ***can*** directly scale components *without* entering **Edit Component** mode, but it's ***not*** something I recommend as a preferred workflow, both because it's not precise and because for more complex components, it will change the relative scales of thickened planes, and thus distort your mesh.

However, if you double-click the component (or right-click) to enter into **Edit Component** mode, you can then orbit your mesh and use the **Push-Pull** tool on the small face at the bottom of the legs up exactly 1'-0" and as they're components, all the other legs will update. This is exactly what component are for.

[image]

---

Though I rarely use SketchUp these days, I used to for building *massive* architectural and planning models for an architecture firm, and I'll tell you that in a context like that, *groups* and *components* are essential parts of the workflow, as is the Outliner.

Hope that helps.